# Form GET and redirect possible?

Tags: forms, redirect, get

I am having trouble figuring out how to set the form to submit a string to an affiliate but also redirecting the user to my own hosted thank you page.  I am using the GET method to submit the string.

this is a very dumbed down version of my form

```
<form action="http://xxxxx.com/api/post.ashx" method="get">                                                 
<div>
<label ><span>First Name <font style="color: red;">*</font></span></label>
<input type="text"  name="First" value="" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />
</div>
<div >
<label ><span>Last Name <font style="color: red;">*</font></span></label>
<input type="text"  name="Last" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />
</div>
<div >
<label ><span>Phone Number <font style="color: red;">*</font></span></label>
<input class="form-text" type="text" maxlength="14" name="phone1" id="phone1" value="">
</div>

</div>                                                      
<input class="form-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Submit" />
</div></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, iframe is a kinda solution here.

Comment: I need 2 things to happen when the form is submitted.  I need the form url string to be submitted to an outside url with GET method.  At the same time i need the user who just filled out the form to be redirected to my thank you page hosted on my site.

Comment: create iframe to external resource, submit it with synchronous AJAX GET (dunno, maybe you'll have to look for crossdomain.xml, but AFAIR, it's not required for sync GET), wait to complete that GET, then redirect user to your own page with setting document.location. You can use jquery to do it without a deep knowledge in js